# kaminari friendly URLs and rails url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, kaminari

```
courses_path
```

This path generate a url:

```
http://localhost:3000/courses
```

With friendly urls:

```
resources :courses, :only => [:index] do
  get 'page/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
end
```

When I want paginate many courses, the urls output is something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/page/2
http://localhost:3000/courses/page/3
http://localhost:3000/courses/page/4
.
.
.
```

For the first page the url is `courses_path` or `courses_url`

```
http://localhost:3000/courses
```

**What is the link helper for each page generated by kaminari?**

Answer (score 2):

You can try following configuration:

```
get '/courses(/page/:page)' => 'courses#index', :as => :courses, :page => 1
```